# Visual Studio 2008 does not display CZ diacritics

Tags: diacritics

I have a problem with the program in Visual Studio 2008.

In the texts defined in resources such as STRING letters are not displayed (ř, č, ě). 
Texts defined in the dialogs are fine. 
The problem is with Visual Studio 2008 (maybe) :( In contrast, the 2006 version is not a problem.

Can you help me to solve this problem? 
Thanks :)